# Why this java code return negative value, and how can I convert it to delphi?

Tags: java, delphi

```
v = -6833708440360172059

public static byte[] longToBytes(long v) {
    byte[] p = new byte[8];
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        p[7-i] = (byte) ((v >>> 8*i) & 0xff);
        System.out.println("p="+ p[i]);
    }

    return p;
}
```

The result:

```
p=0
p=0
p=0
p=0
p=73
p= -66
p=69
p= -27
```

//======================================

My Delphi code:

```
Function TForm1.U64TO8( v : UInt64): TByteArray;
var

  i : Integer;

 p : TByteArray;//array [0..7] of byte;

    begin
      SetLength(p, 8);

      for i:= 0 to 7 do
        p[7-i] := byte( (v SHR (8 * i) ) and $ff );

end;
```

//==================================

result:

```
p=0
p=0
p=0
p=0
p=73
p=190
p=69
p=229
```

Comment: The data in the byte is the same.  If there is a problem it is in not being obvious that the data is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bytes are signed in Java. In Delphi, to replicate this code you would need to use an equivalent [type](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Delphi_Data_Types). Specifically [`Shortint`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Shortint), a signed 8 bit integer. Furthermore, `long` is a signed 64 bit type in Java. In Delphi you need [`Int64`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Int64).

I don't particularly want to reproduce your Java code though because it only prints 4 of the bytes. Surely you don't want to do that?

You might code it like this:

```
function GetSignedBytes(Value: Int64): TArray<Shortint>;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(Result, 8);
  for i := 0 to 7 do 
    Result[7-i] := Shortint(Value shr (8*i));
end;
```

Note that Delphi's `shr` is unsigned shift right, which matches your Java code's `>>>`.

Comment: This not my Java code, I just want to understand it to convert it to delphi. Is there any way to convert Int64 to byte Array, and get same result of java code?

Comment: Change the types as I said and you are there.

Comment: I already change UInt64 to Int64, but I get same result, nothing change. "Thanks"

Comment: There's no way that you get a value greater than 127 in a Shortint. So what you say in that comment cannot be true. Unless you are still using byte in the delphi.

Comment: @Shdotcom - don't forget to accept this if it is the right answer.

Comment: @Remy You are wrong. Delphi shr is unsigned. The docs don't state it, but it so. The compiler emits `shr`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: fair enough.

Answer (score 1):

A byte in Java is signed (i.e. the values are  between -128 and 127). Based on the Delphi code output (I don't know Delphi), bytes in Delphi are unsigned. 190 in an unsigned byte is the same as -66 in a signed byte.